# how to download an original image or video with the baseUrl of Google Photos API?

Tags: google-photos-api

I want to use the REST Google Photos API to download original photos or videos from Goolge Photos, and I found there is no way to achieve it with the "baseUrl".

I have checked the following pages, but there is not a definitive answer:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112096115
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80149160

So if there is indeed a way to get the original photos and videos or if there will be one?

Answer (score 9):

The addition of '=d' will not give you the original file! I tested it. The quality and resolution of the image seems to match the original one, but some information like exif metadata (geo location) is missing. As a result, the file size is also smaller than the original. This makes is not usable for backup synchronization where I want the original file.

Actually, I expect from google that they give me automated access to my own original data. It looks like that is currently not the case.

I'm afraid there are currently only two options how to get the original fotos:

- Manual download on Google Fotos
- Manual download via Google Takeout

Very disappointing!

Answer (score 3):

So I just read through the issue tracker answers you provided, and I noticed that one reply was to add '=d'to the baseUrl.

So example: `GET https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/lr/AGb3...HG2n=d`